# concat a lot of files to stdout

Tags: bash, pipeline

I have a large number of files in directory - ~100k. I want to combine them and pipe them to standard output (I need that to upload them as one file elsewhere), but `cat $(ls)` complains that `-bash: /bin/cat: Argument list too long`. I know how to merge all those files into a temporary one, but can I just avoid it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a start, `cat $(ls)` is not the right way to go about this - `cat *` would be more appropriate. If the number of files is too high, you can use `find` like this:

```
find -exec cat {} +
```

This combines results from `find` and passes them as arguments to `cat`, executing as many separate instances as needed. This behaves much in the same way as `xargs` but doesn't require a separate process or the use of any non-standard features like `-print0`, which is only supported in some versions of `find`.

`find` is recursive by default, so you can specify a `-maxdepth 1` to prevent this if your version supports it. If there are other things in the directory, you can also filter by `-type` (but I guess there aren't, based on your original attempt).

Answer (score 3):

```
 find . -type f -print0 |xargs -0 cat
```

`xargs` will invoke `cat` several times, each time with as many arguments as it can fit on the command line (the combined length of the args can be no more than `getconf ARG_MAX`).

`-print0` (seperate files with `\0`) for `find` in combination with `-0` (process files separated with `\0`) for `xargs` is just a good habit to follow as it will prevent the commands from breaking on filenames with special or white characters in them.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks! Never knew about such cleverness of `xargs`.

Comment: `find` is perfectly capable of doing the same thing all by itself. There's absolutely no need to involve `xargs` or any non-standard features of `find` like `-print0`.

Comment: I see. I didn't know `find` could do this without invoking one `cat` instance for each and every arg. +1 for your answer. Still, I like the Unixly seperation of concerns of the `find` + `xargs` solution. `xargs` is nice. It was made for this kind of thing and it can do other related convenient stuff like paralellization or string-replace placeholders.